# Why these random variable converge a.s. to these constant?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $(X_n)_{n \geq 2}$ are indipendent and identically distributed with exponential density with parameter $\lambda >0$.

I know that $Y=\liminf X_n$ and $Z=\limsup X_n$ are $C_{\infty}$-measurable where $C_{\infty}=\bigcap C_n$ and where $C_n=\sigma (X_k: k \geq n)$ and thus we have that there exists $a,b$ such that $Y=a$ a.e. and $Z=b$ a.e.
But why can I conclude $a=0$ and $b=\frac{1}{\lambda}$?

Comment: I assume there is some typo in the definition of either $X$ or $Y$.

Comment: @Ian I edited the question.

Comment: $b \neq 1/\lambda$. For $a$, look at the number of times we have $\{X_n\leq \epsilon\}$.

Comment: I agree with Michael, $b$ should probably be essential supremum, in this case $\infty$. Another way could be (as you already know $\lim \inf X_n , \lim \sup X_n$ converge a.e) looking at sequences $W_n = \inf_{k \ge n} X_k, V_n = \sup_{k \ge n} X_k$ and finding it limits in probability. This way you can find that $a=0$ and there is no $b \in \mathbb R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically an exercise on Borel-Cantelli Lemma. $\sum P(X_n \leq \frac  1k)=\sum P(X_1 \leq \frac  1k)=\infty$  and hence $X_n \leq \frac 1 k $  for infinitely many $n$ with probability $1$. This implies that $Y \leq \frac 1 k$ for infinitely many $n$ with probability $1$. This is true for each $k$ so $Y=0$ a.s.

The second part is wrong. $\sum P(X_n >N)=\sum P(X_1 >N)=\infty$ so $X_n >N$ for infinitely many $n$ with probability $1$. This is true for each $N$ so $Z=\infty$ a.s..

Comment: I'm glad my hint was helpful to you in solving this.